# Is it possible to convert various Unicode escape sequences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

From the Python [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html):

```
>>> s = "a\xac\u1234\u20ac\U00008000"
... #     ^^^^ two-digit hex escape
... #         ^^^^^^ four-digit Unicode escape
... #                     ^^^^^^^^^^ eight-digit Unicode escape

>>> print(s)
a¬ሴ€耀
```

Is it possible to express the Unicode 4 escape sequence `"\u20ac"` with only hex escapes? Why, for example wouldn't `"\x20\xac"` work?

And the same for the escape sequence `\U00008000"`. Would it be possible to write that with only a hex- or Unicode 4 escape?

Comment: Each escape sequence is a unicode character. Don't confuse escape sequences in Unicode strings with UTF-8 encoding (or some other encoding). Note: `'\u20ac'.encode('utf8')` is `b'\xe2\x82\xac'`, not `b'\x20\xac'`.

Comment: [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> "\u20ac"
'€'
>>> "\x20\xac"
' ¬'
>>> "\U00008000"
'耀'
>>> "\u8000"
'耀'
>>> "\U00008000" == "\u8000"
True
```

let us know if you have more questions ;)